# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter only loads 1 item

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

JSON

```
{     
"Country" : 
 {
"Cabana" : "Sydney",
"Pub" : "China",
"SkyGarden" : "Indonesia",
"Tito" : "Vietnam"
 }
}
```

Main Activity Code.

```
 mDatabaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Country");
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<String, ViewHolder>adapter= new          FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<String, ViewHolder>(String.class,R.layout.xyz,ViewHolder.class,mDatabaseReference){

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, String model, int position) {
            viewHolder.Name.setText("Name + "+model);
            // viewHolder.Serial.setText(String.valueOf(model.Serial));

        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The recycler View shows only 1 item. Name + Australia.
How can I load more items?

[How to Retrieve a List object from the firebase in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744224/how-to-retrieve-a-list-object-from-the-firebase-in-android)

I have gone through this post and even the Android chat App but I couldn't really understand it.

Answer (score 4):

There are to common  problems: you can use incorrect height of row elements and you can import some project where the Recycler view worked horyzontally.
To check for both of these problems, you can:

1. Try swiping up/down (then you will see next element on next screen, because it will take the whole screen). In this case, you `R.layout.xyz` probably has root view with `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and you should change it to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
2. Try swiping left/right (probably you will see next element on the left/right of current). Check that in your layout you haven't specified                `android:orientation="horizontal"` for your RecyclerView.