# How to retrieve a list of all values in Firebase?

Tags: android, arraylist, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an Android application using Firebase. I need to get all the values in the below tree into an `ArrayList`. But I'm getting `NullPointerException`. I've shown my database and code below. Please help me out.
It is different from the question in [How to Retrieve a List object from the firebase in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744224/how-to-retrieve-a-list-object-from-the-firebase-in-android?rq=1)
 I'm trying to retreive3 a list of strings and not objects. I can't find any examples for this.

[image: Here's my firebase database]

Here's the code:

```
brandRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://stockmanager-142503.firebaseio.com/Brands ");
brandRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            allBrands.add(ds.getValue(String.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

The reference to the db works fine. I can add values with no trouble.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException at com.strokx.user.stockmanager.AddItemFragment$2.onDataChange(AddItemFragment.java:93)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzakg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalg.zzcxk(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalj$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3):

In your callback (Suppose you want to get `person` properties then):

```
brandRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

           MeetingUser person = ds.getValue(Person.class);

           String id = person.getId();
           String name= person.getName();

           // Then add the value you require to add in your ArrayList
           allBrands.add(name);
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`getKey()` function is appropriate here.

```
brandRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://stockmanager-142503.firebaseio.com/Brands ");
brandRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            allBrands.add(ds.getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```