# Error: The non-generic type 'GenericTypeIndicator' cannot be used type arguments

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to the implementation of queries in firebase. Below in my code, i am fetching data using snapshot into my list view. I am passing List but reading further, I came across that List cannot be casted to Datasnaphot and the answer requires the use of `GenericTypeIndicator`. I tried using that to get my data into my listView but that would not do the trick.

Why do i get this error `Error: The non-generic type 'GenericTypeIndicator'  cannot be used type arguments.`?

**Activity**

```
     GenericTypeIndicator<List<GetUserContent>>messages = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<GetUserContent>>(){};


 public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
        {
            messages.Clear();
            var items = snapshot.Child(post_key);
            messages.Add((GetUserContent)items);
            ViewAdapter adapter = new ViewAdapter(this, messages);
            Console.WriteLine("Data being fetched " + items);
            mylistview.Adapter = adapter;
        }
```

**Adapter**

```
internal class ViewAdapter: BaseAdapter
    {
        private  List<GetUserContent> messages;

        public ViewAdapter(Activity activity,List<GetUserContent> messages)
        {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.messages = messages;
        }
```

**GetUserContent Class**

```
internal class GetUserContent
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public GetUserContent()
        {

        }

        public GetUserContent(string Email, string Message){

            this.Email = Email;
            this.Message = Message;
        }
```

}

**post**

```
mLike.Child(post_key).Child(mAuth.CurrentUser.Uid).Push().SetValue(edtChat.Text);
```

Comment: Post the definition of `GenericTypeIndicator`

Comment: @dcg i don't have any definition :).  I made my further readings here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30744224/how-to-retrieve-a-list-object-from-the-firebase-in-android/35979715

Comment: @dcg, what did you mean by your statement thought?

Comment: I thought that it was some type you code, I just wanted to see its definition to analyse the error and give you (if possible) my help.

Comment: @dcg I am able to get the items that is being fetched but i am having a hard time passing it to my list view

Answer (score 0):

> Why do i get this error Error: The non-generic type 'GenericTypeIndicator'  cannot be used type arguments.?

I don't know how is this library is designed, and why `GenericTypeIndicator` can not be used with type arguments. You can raise a question on [GooglePlayServicesComponents Github Repo](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents).

But referring to [Work with Lists of Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data). the object you retrieved is a `Java.Lang.IIterable<DataSnapShot>` object，which can not be casted to List directly. You can use the following codes to  cast to List:

```
public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
{
    var children = snapshot.Child("users")?.Children?.ToEnumerable<DataSnapshot>();
    List<HashMap> list = new List<HashMap>();

    foreach (DataSnapshot s in children)
    {
        list.Add((HashMap)s.Value);
    }
}
```

And my Firebase Database structure is like below:

[image]

**Update:**

Currently, I am not able to post my self-defined object directly, I keep getting
 Serialization error:

```
`Firebase.Database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class md5f5cedb36bdcec41a9de7aed50a9aade0.User`.
```

But I workaround it by using `HashMap` as intermediate type:

```
public class User:Java.Lang.Object
{
    public User() {}

    // convert current User to HashMap
    public HashMap ToMap()
    {
        HashMap map = new HashMap();
        map.Put("username", this.username);
        map.Put("email", this.email);
        return map;
    }


    public string username;
    public string email;

    public User(string username, string email)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

And Post the Data like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.Instance
                .Reference
                .Child("users")
                .Push()
                .SetValue(new User("username", "email").ToMap());
```

And it is not completed to retrieve the `HashMap` and convert it back to `User` list:

```
public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
{
    var children = snapshot.Child("users")?.Children?.ToEnumerable<DataSnapshot>();
    List<User> list = new List<User>();

    HashMap map;
    foreach (DataSnapshot s in children)
    {
        map = (HashMap)s.Value;
        list.Add(new User(map.Get("username")?.ToString(), map.Get("email")?.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: so i have to change my the List in my adapter also to HashMap? Because after trying your answer, i am trying to pass the list to my adapter, and it gives an error saying `cannot convert from HashMap to GetUserContent`

Comment: No, `HashMap` is just the type I used to post the data. It's just an example, you should use your `GetUserContent` to replace it.

Comment: The GetUserContent is actually  a class i created to return the user's message time and message content and i believe it can't work like how the HashMap is working. You might want to see my GetUserContent

Comment: When i replace the HashMap with the GetUserContent, one this line `                list.Add((GetUserContent)s.Value); i get the error `cannot convert Java.Lang.Object to GetuserContent`
`

Comment: Are you sure you posted the data using `GetuserContent` objects? Also, Please make sure your database structure only has the level list data like the picture in my answer.

Comment: Yes. i do have something similar. I am sure the types are not matching.Thats why it is asking me to convert the data. I don't post my data using `GetuUserContent`

Comment: Please look at my update. that is how i post data. Is there any way i can post using `GetUserContent` to save me from the conversion stress?

Comment: @Switz I'm suffering from serialization error when post my `User` object directly. But I workaround this using `HashMap`. And I think it is also a good choice for you. Please check my update.

Comment: Hash map is working for me but i can't see the data. When i click on the screen i deploy my app, i see the data is fetched but i can't see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147775/discussion-between-elvis-xia-msft-and-switz).